# Variable sharing between multiple instances of Azure Webapp

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have one azure webapp having 2 instance. i am using node.js to run my server.
below is my code

```
let tmpArr = []
app.get('/get-value', function(req, res){
    res.send({ varValue: tmpArr});
})
app.post('/set-value', function(req, res){
    tmpArr.push(/*Some random number*/)
    res.send({ varValue: tmpArr});
})
```

first when i hit `/set-value` request, it set some random number, let say 10 to `tmpArr` variable, and when i hit `get-value` it return me sometime blank and sometime `10`
what i think is, when i have hit `set` request it may be served by instance 1 and when i hit `get` request it may be served by instance 2 so it not returning me anything.

so what is solution for this problem ? what i want is let say there is N numbers of instances, and it should write same arr Variable and return value either it served by instance 1 or instance N.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what i want is let say there is N numbers of instances, and it should write same arr Variable and return value either it served by instance 1 or instance N.

Welcome to the world of stateless web apps ;-)

If you need shared state between multiple instances you need some centralized store. Could be a fully fledged database, a [distributed cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/distributed-caching) like Redis or something like a durable azure function that use [entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-entities?tabs=csharp) to store the state.

As an added bonus state will be kept when the app service plan is restarted.